# Dataframe set cells issue from dataframe generated with dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to parse a huge file resulting from auto-test in order to return a csv file which collect only interesting elements in order to make it a lot more clear.

So I first create dataframe which I append with a dictionary.

Once I finished to parse the file I wish to initialise one of the column of the dataframe (this column is the effective duration). I can't initialise this column while appending the dataframe because the rows are not sorted correctly.
But nor the at and loc function works correctly.

An example is better than thousands of words:

```
import os, sys, re
import pandas as pd
import datetime

dfObj = pd.DataFrame(columns=['test number', 'test name','passed', 'duration', 'eff duration'])

Dict1 = {'index':3,'test number': 3,'test name':'name1','passed':"1",'duration':10,'eff duration':None}
Dict2 = {'index':2,'test number': 2,'test name':'name2','passed':"0",'duration':12,'eff duration':None}
Dict3 = {'index':4,'test number': 4,'test name':'name3','passed':"1",'duration':13,'eff duration':None}
dfObj = dfObj.append(Dict1,ignore_index=True)
dfObj = dfObj.append(Dict2,ignore_index=True)
dfObj = dfObj.append(Dict3,ignore_index=True)

dfObj = dfObj.set_index('index')
dfObj = dfObj.sort_index(ascending=True)
dfObj.at[2,'eff duration'] = 10
dfObj.at[1,'eff duration'] = 11
dfObj.at[3,'eff duration'] = 12
dfObj.at[0,'eff duration'] = 0

dfObj.to_csv('auto-test result {}.csv'.format(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')),index=False)
```

and here is the result I get once opening the csv file inside Excel:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it seems the at does not work as expected because of the way I appended my dataframe, the solution was to use iloc instead of at:

```
import os, sys, re
import pandas as pd
import datetime

dfObj = pd.DataFrame(columns=['test number', 'test name','passed', 'duration', 'eff duration'])

Dict1 = {'index':3,'test number': 3,'test name':'name1','passed':"1",'duration':10,'eff duration':None}
Dict2 = {'index':2,'test number': 2,'test name':'name2','passed':"0",'duration':12,'eff duration':None}
Dict3 = {'index':4,'test number': 4,'test name':'name3','passed':"1",'duration':13,'eff duration':None}
dfObj = dfObj.append(Dict1,ignore_index=True)
dfObj = dfObj.append(Dict2,ignore_index=True)
dfObj = dfObj.append(Dict3,ignore_index=True)

dfObj = dfObj.set_index('index')
dfObj = dfObj.sort_index(ascending=True)
dfObj.iloc[0,4] = 1
dfObj.iloc[1,4] = 2
dfObj.iloc[2,4] = 3

dfObj.to_csv('auto-test result {}.csv'.format(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')),index=False)
```

result in Excell:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `dfObj = dfObj.set_index('index')`, you set the index by `index` column. So the value of index is `2`, `3`, `4`.

```
# print(dfObj)

      test number test name passed duration eff duration
index                                                   
2.0             2     name2      0       12         None
3.0             3     name1      1       10         None
4.0             4     name3      1       13         None
```

[pandas.DataFrame.at()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) use row/column label pair to  access a single value.

```py
dfObj.at[1,'eff duration'] = 11
dfObj.at[0,'eff duration'] = 0
```

In above code snippet, `0` and `1` are not in index value `2`, `3`, `4`, that's why pandas creates new rows. Here is an example to assign values for column `eff duration`.

```py
dfObj.at[2,'eff duration'] = 1
dfObj.at[3,'eff duration'] = 2
dfObj.at[4,'eff duration'] = 3
```